# Can we use CSV Data Set Config inside a IF controller in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to drive **CSV Data Set Config** through **IF controller**, how can i achieve this in a single thread group ?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot.

CSV DataSet listens to its parent iterations and pick a new line from file on each iteration.

You can possibly use this function inside If Controller

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead